# How to get the US state code using django-cities-light?

Tags: django

I'm using [django-cities-light](https://django-cities-light.readthedocs.io/en/1.8/index.html) for managing region/state models for US. But I can't see in the model how to retrieve the US state code widely available in GeoNames. e.g: CA for California.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this abstract model field https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light/blob/88b897023f5cc7a0d76adaaf7e36343917ea698b/cities_light/abstract_models.py#L105